# How i can optimize this code that contain some repetitive line?

Tags: java, android

I have below code in android programming

```
Button btn1 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn1 );
Button btn2 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn2 );
Button btn3 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn3 );
Button btn4 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn4 );
Button btn5 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn5 );
Button btn6 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn6 );
Button btn7 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn7 );
Button btn8 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn8 );
Button btn9 = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.btn9 );
```

And it continue untill btn30
In python I optimize it by below easy code

```
#is a python syntax (for_statement)
#python work by tab
for i in range(1,31):
    #in python not need to declare temp
    temp="""Button btn"""+str(i)+"""=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn"""+str(i)+""")"""
    exec(temp)#a default function in python
```

In java programing how i can do it?Or can I do it?do exist a easy code for it?

`UPDATE 1`

SO there are two way to do it
`Code 1`:

```
final int number = 30;
final Button[] buttons = new Button[number];
final Resources resources = getResources();

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    final String name = "btn" + (i + 1);
    final int id = resources.getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());

    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(id);
}
```

`Code 2`:

```
public static int getIdByName(final String name) {
    try {
        final Field field = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        return -1;
    }
}

final Button[] buttons = new Button[30];

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(getIdByName("btn" + (i + 1)));
}
```

And other way is GidView

Comment: use getIdentifier for writing same code in java as in python

Comment: I came across same problem when I was making a Tic-Tac-Toe game and I had 9 buttons to deal with.

Comment: Hint: If you're using `exec` in the Python version, then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create an array of `Button`'s and use `getIdentifier` method that allows you to get an identifier by its name.

```
final int number = 30;
final Button[] buttons = new Button[number];
final Resources resources = getResources();

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    final String name = "btn" + (i + 1);
    final int id = resources.getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());

    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(id);
}
```

**In case someone is interested how to achive the same result using Java only**

The solution above uses `Android` specific methods (such as `getResources`, `getIdentifier`) and can not be used in usual `Java`, but we can use a `reflection` and write a method that works like a `getIdentifier`:

```
public static int getIdByName(final String name) {
    try {
        final Field field = R.id.class.getDeclaredField(name);

        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
final Button[] buttons = new Button[30];

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(getIdByName("btn" + (i + 1)));
}
```

Comment: @MM-BB : write `buttons[1].setonclick` instead of `btn1.setonclick` for setting onClick listener for first button same for others.for example: `buttons[2].setonclick`,`buttons[3].setonclick`,...

Comment: Is there a way to declare the `onClickListener` for each button inside a loop. Like, `onClickListener` of each button should call a method `fooBar(id)`, where id is the loop counter?

Comment: Great! I needed it for a little Tic-Tac-Toe app I was making and I had 9 buttons to deal with and each button called a `play(id)` method. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of optimizing this kind of code you should rethink your layout. If you have 30 buttons on the screen, a `ListView` is probably the better solution. You can access the items via index and handle `onClick` events just like with the buttons.

Comment: your answer is ok but in other case that we can not use listview

Comment: I strongly believe there is no excuse at all to use 30 buttons in a single layout. There are a lot of AdapterViews available to choose from. Not necessarily a ListView.

Comment: for ex: case that we use some if that is repetive

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [getIndentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method from the `Resources` class, your code will look like this:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("btn" + (i + 1), "id", <your-package-name>);
    buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather go with a simple array of `Button`s.

```
// Just a simple code
Button [] buttons = new Button[30];
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    buttons[i] = new Button();
}
```

If you still need to initialize them with `findViewById()` method, it will be ugly anyway, but still there won't be so much declarations, which is worth considering for me.

Answer (score 1):

With the minum code I can think of I would do this:

```
   Button[]btn=new Button[30];
  for (int i=0;i<btn.length;i++)  btn[i] = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("btn"+(i+1),"id", "yourpackage"));
```